# Machine Learning Classification ensemble

Tags: ensemble-learning

i have a question regarding ensembles of classifiers in machine learning. I have read about [Ensemble methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) but i couldn't put a relate them to what i am thinking.

If i have a few classifiers for a multi-class problem, and some classifiers exhibit better performance for certain classes than others, how can i take advantage of this characteristic in my ensemble?

For example.
Classifier A scores higher F1 in classes 1 compared to the rest. 
Classifier B scores higher F1 in classes 2 compared to the rest.
Classifier C scores higher F1 in classes 3 compared to the rest.
How might i do an ensemble such that i give more weight to the probabilities of class 1 in classifier A and reduce the rest?

I am thinking of a simple 2 layer approach.
Layer 1: For each classifier, internally put a weight across the classes based on their individual class performance and then normalise.
Layer 2: A weight on each classifier based on their overall F1 performance

Would this make sense?

```
Layer1
Model A     Class1      Class2     Class3
Original    0.2         0.5        0.3
Weight      0.2*0.25    0.5*0.5    0.3*0.25
Equals      0.05        0.25       0.075
Normalise   0.133       0.66       0.2
```

```
Layer2
Models      Class1      Class2     Class3
A           0.3*0.133   0.3*0.66   0.3*0.2
B           0.5*blah    0.5*blah   0.5*blah
C           0.2*blah    0.2*blah   0.2*blah
Avg         Avg         Avg        Avg
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why you theoretically could weight differently the outcomes of different models and get a better result, how could you weight them differently based on the class, considering that the task is to find the class?

You can weight some classifiers globally. Also, once a class is determined (i.e. enough classifiers agreed that the class is X), you can reweight the probabilities (e.g. if the ensemble said that the probability is 60% and some trusted classifiers on this class had a high probability, you can make it 80%). However, I am not sure this would help in practice.